# Why doesn't z-index: -1 work in this instance?

Tags: html, css

I need the `<i>` element to appear below the anchor in the stacking order, but nothing seems to work. Suggestions?

```css
a.button {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
a.button i {
  background: rgb(128, 0, 128);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2.5px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#"><i></i>Button</a>
```

Removing `z-index: 1` from the `<a>` results in the `<i>` appearing below parent elements:

```css
div.wrapper {
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px;
}
a.button {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
a.button i {
  background: rgb(128, 0, 128);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2.5px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="button" href="#"><i></i>Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do that in any reliable manner without changing HTML.  If that's an option, great.  Otherwise, the stacking context for your `i` element is the same as that of the `a.button`, and that can't be changed via CSS.

Comment: As josh mentioned this has to do with your hierarchy and stacking context. I *highly* recommend read the entire section of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: @JoshBurgess — Feel free to add that as an answer if you'd like credit…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in any reliable manner without changing HTML. If that's an option, great. Otherwise, the stacking context for your `i` element is the same as that of the `a.button`, and that can't be changed via CSS.